# Problem with Multiple Process Execution in c

Tags: c, linux, process, ipc

I'm currently trying to create 2 child processes, and each child print something, the problem is one of the processes prints twice instructions of 'printf'.
here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(void)
{
    pid_t childPid[2];
    if((childPid[0] = fork()) == 0)
        printf("Hello I'm process one\n");
    if((childPid[1] = fork()) == 0)
        printf("Hello I'm process two\n");  
    return 0;
}
```

and here's the result after compiling & running:

```
Hello I'm process one
Hello I'm process two
Hello I'm process two
```

Any explanation of why the second process was executed twice please.

Comment: The way you have coded it results in the first child also calling `fork`. So you are creating more than two child processes.

Comment: OT:  the function: `fork()` returns 3 kinds of info:  <0 means an error occurred  ==0 means in child process >0 means in parent process.  Your code should be checking for all 3 conditions

Answer (score 2):

After the first `fork` call, the first child process continues to execute the rest of the program as well i.e. both the parent as well as the first child processes call `fork` again.

You just to exit the first child process, so that only the parent calls the second fork:

```
if((childPid[0] = fork()) == 0) {
    printf("Hello I'm process one\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: I pretty much come to understand the idea, you're saying that i need to use exit(0) once a process finished its work, because If I don't that process will continue to execute the code that comes after it. So it's like when I create a new process, it inherits the code that comes after if I don't exit or something like that?

Comment: exiting, gives control back to the parent process

Comment: `fork` duplicates the calling process and everything from that point onwards will be executed in both processes. "exiting, gives control back to the parent process" - no, exiting simply ends *that* process - there's no "giving control" there. The parent continues to run regardless. The exit is to prevent the child process executing the rest of the program.

Answer (score 0):

In the following code, you spawned a child process and there're 2 processes running, parent and child. A parent process can be identified by the return value of `fork()`, which prints a message but did NOT exit. That's why you see more one message on the next `printf()` result.

```
if((childPid[0] = fork()) == 0)
        printf("Hello I'm process one\n");
```

Because neither of parent or child has exited, the following code would be excuted by 2 processes, both parent and child, which results in showing the same message twice.

```
if((childPid[1] = fork()) == 0)
        printf("Hello I'm process two\n");
```

It is common that a child process executes an additional job and return whereas parent process continue its main flow. So, as a result, I prefer writing,

```
childPid[0]=fork();
if(childPid[0]<0)
{
  // error
}
else if(childPid[0] == 0) // following code would be executed by child process only
{
  printf("Hello I'm Child process two\n");
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Thank you John for the explanation